# Why use ActiveSupport::Concern instead of just a plain module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I never understood why one has to use ActiveSupport::Concern is used for mixins instead of a plain module. Is there a simple answer to what ActiveSupport::Concern provides (at least in Rails 5) that a simple module without using ActiveSupport::Concern will do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html:

A typical module looks like this:

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
    base.class_eval do
      scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

By using `ActiveSupport::Concern` the above module could instead be written as:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module M
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :disabled, -> { where(disabled: true) }
  end

  class_methods do
    ...
  end
end
```

Moreover, it gracefully handles module dependencies. Given a `Foo` module and a `Bar` module which depends on the former, we would typically write the following:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def self.method_injected_by_foo
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  def self.included(base)
    base.method_injected_by_foo
  end
end

class Host
  include Foo # We need to include this dependency for Bar
  include Bar # Bar is the module that Host really needs
end
```

But why should `Host` care about `Bar`'s dependencies, namely `Foo`? We could try to hide these from `Host` directly including `Foo` in `Bar`:

```
module Bar
  include Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.method_injected_by_foo
  end
end

class Host
  include Bar
end
```

Unfortunately this won't work, since when `Foo` is included, its base is the `Bar` module, not the `Host` class. With `ActiveSupport::Concern`, module dependencies are properly resolved:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Foo
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    def self.method_injected_by_foo
      ...
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  include Foo

  included do
    self.method_injected_by_foo
  end
end

class Host
  include Bar # It works, now Bar takes care of its dependencies
end
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and only repeats the documentation. If you aren't using a mixture of class and instance methods, I don't think there is a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

One reason to use ActiveSupport::Concern over a regular mixin is that it lazy loads the includes. Therefore, if you are referencing code in a model, controller, etc., it will resolve. Whereas you may get undefined errors when a mixin is loaded.